# .on() handler not working on element created with .html(), why?

Tags: jquery

The following code adds data to the container #section via ajax:

```
$(".btnGetImages").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // get id of article
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    // get images via ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/get_images.php",
        type: "get",
        data: {article:id},
        success: function(data) {
            // insert data into container
            $("#section").html(data);
        },
        error:function() {
            $("#section").html('show error msg here...');
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the container #section there are elements with a class .thumb that i would like to click. For some reason, the click doesn't trigger, even though i added the .on event correctly. Why?

```
$(".thumb").on("click", function(event) {
    alert('yo, im a thumb...');

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Event delegation.....

Comment: @null: i've read about delegation, but it says delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method...

Comment: So did you read about how to do event delegation with `on()`? Apparently not, because that's not what you wrote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207033/jquery-on-event-doesnt-work-for-dynamically-added-element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: These answers aren't even anywhere near accurate. You need to re-bind event listeners to **dynamically generated content** which means you need to re-specify any .delegate or .on or .whatever functions used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they were dynamically created, you need to use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Use `'#section'` as the selector, as it's more efficient than using `document`:

```
$("#section").on("click", ".thumb", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('yo, im a thumb...');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to re-apply any event handlers to any dynamically generated code.

```
function foo() {
    alert('foo');
}

$('body').html('<p>something in here</p>');
$('body p').on('click', foo);
```

The best way is to pre-define a function and then assign it as your event handler. When jQuery is loaded it runs through the HTML code and assigns any defined event handlers to any HTML code that **exists**. If you add to the document, the event listeners don't exist, so you need to re-apply them.